# How to create UI elements programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, user-interface

I'd like to be able to create new UI elements (a UIProgressView bar) in a separate UIViewController every time a user taps on a button.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Based on an action in viewController1, you want a progress view to be shown when viewController2 appears? If so you could use a notification that viewController2 listens for.  Create the progress view when you receive the notification.

Comment: Exactly this... How different is using notifications vs using appDelegate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a UIProgressView programmatically, it is simply a matter of using alloc and init, setting a frame, and adding a subview, like so:

```
//.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ExampleViewController : UIViewController {

    //create the ivar
    UIProgressView *_progressView;

}
/*I like to back up my iVars with properties.  If you aren't using ARC, use retain instead of strong*/
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIProgressView *progressView;

@end

//.m

@implementation
@synthesize progressView = _progressView;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    /* it isn't necessary to create the progressView here, after all you could call this code from any method you wanted to and it would still work*/
    //allocate and initialize the progressView with the bar style
    self.progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    //add the progressView to our main view.
    [self.view addSubview: self.progressView];
    //if you ever want to remove it, call [self.progressView removeFromSuperView];

}
```

Comment: No problem.  If you don't know how to code UI, I recommend you bone up as quickly as possible!

Answer (score 1):

Read this guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html

Most of the UI elements create like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect];
//  set the property of the view here
//  ...

//  finally add your view
[ViewController.view addSubView:view];
```